# Reading information from a txt file and storing it in a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I need to take information from a txt file and store it into a dictionary

Only one line of the information is being stored in the dictionary, How do I have all the lines get stored?

```
text = '''
admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program., 10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No
admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No

'''


tasks = {}

with open('tasks.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    
    for line in file:
        temp = line.split(", ")
        user = temp[0]
        title = temp[1]
        description = temp[2]
        due_date = temp[3]
        date_assigned = temp[4]
        status = temp[5]
        
        tasks[user] = {'title': title, 'description': description, 'due date': due_date, 'date assigned': date_assigned, 'status': status}

print(tasks)
```

Comment: Please don't give external links or screenshots of your data. Post a reasonably sized sample of your data as text.

Comment: Alright, I'll edit it now

Comment: tasks is a dictionary as you intend. So it only accepts unique entries and duplicates are over-ridden. Both lines in the txt file have user `admin` hence only one entry.

Answer (score 0):

you have the same key `admin` in your result dictionary, the first one is replaced by the second one, so modify you text file to give different names.
if you have multi assignment for one user, you can use following code:

```
text = '''
admin, Register Users with taskManager.py, Use taskManager.py to 
add the usernames and passwords for all team members that will be 
using this program., 10 Oct 2019, 20 Oct 2019, No
admin, Assign initial tasks, Use taskManager.py to assign each team 
member with appropriate tasks, 10 Oct 2019, 25 Oct 2019, No

'''


tasks = {}

with open('tasks.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:

 for line in file:
    temp = line.split(", ")
    user = temp[0]
    title = temp[1]
    description = temp[2]
    due_date = temp[3]
    date_assigned = temp[4]
    status = temp[5]

    if user in list(tasks):
        tasks[user].append({'title': title, 'description': description,
                            'due date': due_date, 'date assigned': date_assigned, 'status': status})
    else:
        tasks[user] = [{'title': title, 'description': description,
                        'due date': due_date, 'date assigned': date_assigned, 'status': status}]

print(tasks)
```

this should print:

```
{'admin': [{'title': 'Register Users with taskManager.py', 'description': 'Use taskManager.py to add the usernames and passwords for all team members that will be using this program.', 'due date': '10 Oct 2019', 'date assigned': '20 Oct 2019', 'status': 'No\n'}, {'title': 'Assign initial tasks', 'description': 'Use taskManager.py to assign each team member with appropriate tasks', 'due date': '10 Oct 2019', 'date assigned': '25 Oct 2019', 'status': 'No\n'}]}
```

Comment: I need to have different tasks for the same user in this case admin. Will I not be able to do this with a dictionary?

Comment: you can use a list as value for the key name `admin` instead of a dictionary, for example: `{"admin": [{'title':'assigment1'.....}, {"title':'assignment2'....}]}`

Comment: @theramannoodle, you won't be able to do this with a dictionary. A dictionary does not allow duplicate keys in it.